# HTML elements created by the content script are not accessible by the content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Within content script I use on.Message.addListener to add images with a class name to the currently active web page.

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

```
// Selecting HTML tags
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

// Creating a full URL to use icon1
var imageUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("icons/icon1.png");

// Function to create an image
function PlaceImage(source_x, source_y, imageUrl) {

    var newImage = document.createElement("img");

    newImage.src = imageUrl;

    newImage.style.position = "absolute";
    newImage.style.left = source_x + 'px';
    newImage.style.top = source_y + 'px';

    // Assigning a class name
    newImage.className = "label-key";

    // Add an element to the HTML document
    document.body.appendChild(newImage);

}

// Divs
for(var j=0; j<divs.length; j++) {

    // Get the position of an element with getBoundingClientRect
    var position = divs[j].getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = position.left;
    var y = position.top;
    y -=32;

    // Create comment image
    PlaceImage(x, y, imageUrl);
}
```

});

Later I try to write to console by clicking on one of just created images by:

```
$(".label-key").click(function () {
    console.log("hello");
});
```

There is no reaction of the browser.

I tried to write to console by accessing some class element with a different name, which was part of the original web page(received from the server). It worked fine.

More over I created another element within content script, but this time outside of onMessage.AddListener:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
newDiv.style.width = "100px";
newDiv.style.height = "100px";
newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
newDiv.className = "label-key";
```

It also worked fine. jQuery was able to access this element.

Therefore, I think there is something wrong with html elements created by the onMessage.addListener part of content script.

For additional reference: when I right-click on the newly created element "Inspect element" - I can see that the element is part of the html document. However, if I click "View page source" the element is not there.

Comment: Relevant parts of code missing from your question.

Comment: what would you like to see?

Comment: Your `onMessage` listener, of course, and where is that `click` handler assigned.

Comment: I have added the listener. The click handler is in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are creating a new element of the class `label-key`, but the `click` handler assignment does not automagically extend to newly-created elements.

`$(".label-key").click(...)` is not behaving like a CSS rule despite looking like one: it collects all elements *that match at the time of invocation* and binds a listener for them.

So, if you add more images later, you need to add a click handler again:

```
function PlaceImage(source_x, source_y, imageUrl) {

    var newImage = document.createElement("img");

    newImage.src = imageUrl;

    newImage.style.position = "absolute";
    newImage.style.left = source_x + 'px';
    newImage.style.top = source_y + 'px';

    // Assigning a class name
    newImage.className = "label-key";
    newImage.click(function () {
      console.log("hello");
    });

    // Add an element to the HTML document
    document.body.appendChild(newImage);

}
```

Comment: I've put the click handler inside the PlaceImage function but the new elements are still not accessible. You say that the elements are collected at the moment of invocation. Is there any way to collect them at some specific time/state? Either check periodically or after recent user's interaction?

Comment: You can try and look into [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). But my approach should in principle work.

Comment: I believe `$("document").on("click",".label-key",function(){console.log("hello");});` is designed with this in mind.